# SSIS package deployment erros - create master key in DB or open the master key in the session

Tags: sql, sql-server, git, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am trying to deploy my SSIS package and stepping into the error create master key in DB or open the master key in the session

1. I have changed the password sensitivity to be 'Dont save sensitive' for the project and package
2. Right Click on Projects(Integration Services Catalog ) and run through the wizard, this errors comes in the last step.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Has someone created the actual SSISDB? Have you been able to deploy any packages to the catalog previously?

Comment: No this is the first package being deployed in the server, the SSIDB was created by someone else

Comment: Excellent, then the next question. Have *you* deployed a package to this server before? Has something about this environment changed recently? Like, there was a restore or something

Comment: @billinkc No I have not deplyed any package to this server. Nothing regarding the environment changed except it was slow and we had to delete few snapshots and reboot it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out how to solve this.

1. Drop the master key and create a new one if there are no other packages in your SSISDB. If there are other packages you should find a way out.
2. Save the master key in a back up location on the server and copy the password for later use.
3. The next is create service accounts with permissions to mitigate the keys across domain controllers.
4. Use the service account and change the logon  for the SSIS,SQL Server Engine and Sql server Agent in the Windows services GUI.
5. Restart all the services mentioned above.
6. This will resolve the issue.